# How to Print charts in Mathematica 10 Report Generator?

Tags: mathematica, mathematica-notebook

I want to be able to collect the resulting plots from an evaluated notebook into another notebook with only the output I specify. Basically I want to be able to evaluate a notebook and collect together the resulting plots without the code into a report of some kind so that I can print it out in a pdf and bring it to meetings.

Report Generator seemed like the way to do this. So I made a notebook and began setting code I wanted to hide to "Evaluate and Hide" and left the output I wanted to see in the report unsuppressed. I found out that the output of `Print[]` does not show up in the generated report (notebook). And I kind of need it to. So, how can I evaluate a notebook and hide the code, showing only the output I specify with `Print[]` or unsuppressed output?

I tried the `AutoCollapse[]` method from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/680/how-to-keep-input-cells-hidden-after-evaluating-notebook). But it does not seem to work.

Comment: You might post the version of Mathematica you are using.